# DocuSign for SF - Send & Attach to Custom Object

Tags: custom-object, docusign

I was wondering if it's possible to have DocuSign "live" on a custom object, instead of the predefined standard objects? I've attempted to 'Connect' the object, as well as created the JS button to send from the Object, but upon signature it's not reattaching. It appears DS is hardcoded to only work with Standard Objects?

Comment: Have you looked though the [DocuSign for Salesforce Administrator's Guide](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign_for_Salesforce_Administrator_Guide.pdf)? Speicifcally, page 40 of the PDF seems to cover this. Also, what do you mean by DocuSign not 'reattaching' to your custom object after signature? Please go into more detail about what you expect to happen after the document is completed though DocuSign.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I'm mostly concerned with the actual .pdf that gets attached to Notes & Attachments upon complete. The guide (page 40) only specifies the DS Status Object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. As Derek F said above, follow the instructions in the `[DocuSign for Salesforce Administrator's Guide][1]` on page 40. Once this is complete, add the "Send With DocuSign" button to your layout. As the envelope progresses, statuses will be updated. When the envelope is completed, a copy of the document will be attached to the custom object.

Note: The link references Salesforce classic view and an older version of the DocuSign layout. However, all the features it references are still there and easy to find.